# Find entities with multiple relations

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

Given a model where

```
Photo
======
id

PhotoConnect
======
outside_name
outside_key
photo_id (foreign key to Photo)
```

How do I find all Photo's with both a `PhotoConnect` with (`outside_name` = `country` and `outside_key` = `6`) and (`outside_name` = `region` and `outside_key` = `13`)?

So far, I've tried inner-joining the tables and `AND WHERE`-ing both, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you want to join the table a second time... match conditions for country or for region

```
SELECT 
    p.id 
FROM Photo p
JOIN PhotoConnect pc on pc.photo_id = p.id
JOIN PhotoConnect pc1 on pc1.photo_id = p.id
WHERE pc.outside_name = 'country' and pc.outside_key = 6 
  AND pc1.outside_name = 'region' and pc1.outside_key = 13
GROUP BY photo_id
```

Comment: Nope, I need the Photo to have both PhotoConnects, so both Country and Region, in this case.

Comment: So basicly joining the PhotoConnect table for every relation I want to find?

Comment: yes.. you could use an IN() but I would want to see some data to make sure it would work

Comment: How would such an `IN` work for data like:

Photo 1
Photo 2
PhotoConnect 'country' 6 1
PhotoConnect 'region' 18 1
PhotoConnect 'airplane' 321 2
PhotoConnect 'bakery' 9 1

Comment: to be honest joins will be faster than IN() so I would just recommend you go about it that way. If you want to make a sql fiddle I can try and create a result set using IN() but it probably will be slower.